# Need an actual Dojox chart widget example, including working file structure

Tags: charts, widget, dojo

can anyone relate to this: i need a ***working example*** of a **Dojox chart widget**, replete WITH file structure, file names, and how to launch the widget? i have a framework set up at work, with working widgets, but am having a tough time understanding how to fit a Dojox chart widget example into this system. already spent many hours and days trying many tutorials which work using the Demo, then "View Source" - that HTML page works. but *how to set up files in directories and run the widget*?

i would really appreciate someone's answer, or references to tutorials *you believe in*. thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Got it - within our framework i took code from dojotoolkit (.org) and put it into 2 of my files. i do not know how your system is set up but basically, wherever your widget.js is, use the javascript for that, in a place where you can enter a function that will run. the .html code will go wherever your widget template/.html file goes. i will leave your paths/directories up to you. here is an example of a dojox bar chart, with associated .js, and .html for the "widget".js and "template".html files, respectively:

```
//.js widget code:
```

```javascript
    require([
             // Require the basic chart class
            "dojox/charting/Chart",

            // Require the theme of our choosing
            "dojox/charting/themes/MiamiNice",

            // Charting plugins:

            //  We want to plot Columns
            "dojox/charting/plot2d/Columns",

            //  We want to use Markers
            "dojox/charting/plot2d/Markers",

            //  We'll use default x/y axes
            "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",

            // Wait until the DOM is ready
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(Chart, theme) {

            // Define the data [
            var chartData = [10000,10000,10000,12000,12000,12000,14200,14200,14200,10000,10000,10000];
            // Create the chart within its "holding" node
            var chart = new Chart("chartNode");

            // Set the theme
            chart.setTheme(theme);

            // Add the only/default plot
            chart.addPlot("default", {
                type: "Columns",
                markers: true,
                gap: 5
            });

            // Add axes
            chart.addAxis("x");
            chart.addAxis("y", { vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major" });

            // Add the series of data
            chart.addSeries("Monthly Sales",chartData);      
            // Render the chart!
            chart.render();

        });
<!-- .html template file code -->
```

```html
<div data-dojo-attach-point="parentNode" role="presentation" tabindex="0" data-dojo-attach-event="onkeypress:onKeyPress, onclick : onClick, onclick : onSelect">
   <div id="myDialog" class="content">
      <div class="decoration"><span class="image" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span></div>
      <div data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode" role="button" aria-selected="false">

        <!-- <div id="CircularGauge" ></div> -->
        <!-- <div id="SemiCircularGauge" ></div> -->
        <div id="chartNode" style="width:280px;height:280px;"></div>

      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

NOTE!!!: the .html code's ==>data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode" already uses this as part of the widget .js file code, so you are responsible for matching your "labelNode" to whatever your widget uses. here is some code in case u can match it to ur setup:

> note, my .html template file is named Button2.html [because
>   originally, my widget was to behave like a button, with onClick
>   functionality. NOW, i only am displaying a chart, but using otherwise
>   the same widget code. NOTE: i also included in the "define" list, ==>
>   "dojox/charting/Chart2D", although now, when i remove it, the chart
>   still works. i'll leave u responsible for your own "define" list :).
>   the MAIN point i'm making is, "_setLabelAttr: {node: "labelNode",
>   type: "innerText"}," uses the "labelNode" here in the widget .js file,
>   which corresponds to the .html template file.

```javascript
define([
   "dojo/_base/declare",
   "dojo/_base/event",
   "dojo/_base/lang",
   "dojo/dom-attr",
   "dojo/dom-class",
   "dojo/dom-style",
   "dojo/keys",
   "dojo/text!theme/html/Button2.html",
   "dijit/_Widget",
   "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
   "dijit/_Contained",
   "com/tgcs/tcx/gravity/base/JSBeanWidget",
   "dojox/charting/Chart2D",
   "dojo/parser",
   "dojo/ready",
   "dijit/_WidgetBase"],
function(declare, event, lang, domAttr, domClass, domStyle, keys, template, _widget, _templated, _contained, JSBeanWidget, Chart2D, parser, ready, _WidgetBase)
{

    var module = declare("um, ur path to your widget file goes here, which has periods, and ends in something like ... ==>.widget.AssociateInfoPost", [_widget, _templated, _contained, JSBeanWidget, _WidgetBase],
   {
      label: "",
      tooltip: "",
      visible: true,
      enabled: true,
      //templateString: template,
      templateString: template,
      langType: "active",
      actionId: "noop",
      isListener: false,
      baseClass: "xcButton",
      _setTooltipAttr: {node: "parentNode", type: "attribute", attribute: "title"},   //called by _WidgetBase
      _setLabelAttr: {node: "labelNode", type: "innerText"},
```

SO, basically, proper .js code + proper .html code allows the .js pointing to the .html template file, and using the right .js code pointing to the node in the .html file, as follows: "_setLabelAttr: {node: "labelNode", type: "innerText"}," - this should display in your widget area, the bar chart graphic. i will cross my fingers for you 8D.

If you have feedback or questions, I'll be happy to try to answer them. d c p a r h a m at gmail c o m.